# WPF Databinding to Custom Collection Objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
Public Sub New(ByVal log As Entities.LogSystem)
    InitializeComponent()   
    Me.DataContext = log
End Sub
```

This is the the initializer for my custom control It passes in a single entity that has several property fields. This control is added to a parent control so that it appears in a stackpanel.

Anyway I am trying to get the specific data from this control into several different text boxes:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LogSystemPickerItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WavelengthIS.WISRED.UserControls"
    Width="579" Height="122">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:LogSystemPickerItem x:Key="Log"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Log}}">
        <Label Height="30" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding deptDescription}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see i havent really gotten too far. I have tried many different ways to do this including using dependency properties...I just really cant find a tutorial that shows this specific circumstance...can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting the `DataContext` in the code behind as per your first code snippet, there's no need to also do it in the XAML, so you can remove the "Log" resource and the corresponding `DataContext` assignment on the `Grid`.

Once you've done that, it should work assuming there is a `deptDescription` property on your log class.

Comment: sweet that worked. BUT...I really would rather have it in the XAML so that I can have designtime access to the control. I had it working with a datagrid, but I couldnt figure out how to do it in the textbox. Also I had a casing issue with the deptDescription should have been DeptDescription. So I have the xaml correct too? its just a matter of either/or?

Answer (score 0):

... and in XAML you may do it this way...

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:LogSystemPickerItem/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: doing it this way causes my IDE to crash.